# Get value of tag using part of the text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get value of "data-value" tag using only part of the text in example - size (EU: 41,5) but I have no idea how to do that.

There's html code of site.

```
<a class="m-productDescr_sizeBtn js-sizeItem js-tooltipHtml js-tooltip_rm" data-tip="    <span>   US: 8,5  </span>
<span>   EU: 41,5  </span>" data-value="787631046" data-carturl="/cart/add?id=787631046" data-hasqtip="1" aria-describedby="qtip-1">
                            41,5
                        </a>
```

I've tried to do this

```
soup.find_all(string=re.compile('EU: 41,5'))
```

but it returns only string containg size.

Answer (score 0):

Use `parent` to get the parents of the elements you found, that's where the `data-value` attribute is.

```
values = [span.parent.attrs['data-value'] for span in soup.find_all(string=re.compile('EU: 41,5'))]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but your solution dont work, I dont know maybe I am doing sth wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
val = """your html above"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
soup = bs(val,'lxml')
dvs = soup.select('a[data-value]')
for dv in dvs:
    print(dv['data-value'])
```

Output:

> 787631046

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it's not the solution i was looking for. The problem is that i'm using  link to site and there are many sizes so your solution just show me one size which i dont want ;/

Comment: @Kompocik - It works with the html you posted. Can't speak for anything else.